# Get OrgUnits by OrgUnitType

Tags: desire2learn, valence

I'm attempting to get all OrgUnits using Valence that are the "Department" type.  When I do the call to `/d2l/api/lp/1.4/orgstructure/?orgunittype=Department`, I get a paged result set containing all the OrgUnits

The [docs](http://docs.valence.desire2learn.com/res/orgunit.html#get--d2l-api-lp-%28version%29-orgstructure-) are a little unclear.  They specify that

> You can use the orgUnitType, orgUnitCode, and orgUnitName query parameters as filters to further narrow the list of org units this action retrieves.

and also

> orgUnitType (string) – Optional. Filter to org units of this type.

However, "string" is a bit ambiguous considering OrgUnitType is a composite type with both a code and a name as a string.  Both my Code and my Name for this type is "Department yet it still gives me everything.

Comment: Ah, yes -- the docs are a bit misleading on this; I will make sure they get updated to clarify.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should provide an org unit type identified by a valid `orgUnitTypeId` (for course offerings, this will be `3`.

For custom org unit types, like "Department", the value will most likely vary LMS to LMS:

- You can use the [call to retrieve the list of all known org unit types](http://docs.valence.desire2learn.com/res/orgunit.html#get--d2l-api-lp-%28version%29-outypes-) to determine the type corresponding to "Department" for your LMS.
- Or, because "Department" is one of the very common custom org unity types, you can use [the specific get department-org-unit-type call](http://docs.valence.desire2learn.com/res/orgunit.html#get--d2l-api-lp-%28version%29-outypes-department) to find out what the ID is for that type on your LMS (there's also a specific call like this to get the type ID for "semester" org units).